# Concavity of $\ln(x^\alpha - y)$ function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I would like to prove that $f(x,y) = \ln(x^\alpha - y)$, with $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is strictly concave function. I can prove that $g(x,y) = \ln(x - y)$ is strictly concancave. That is,  let $z_1 = (x_1,y_1)$, $z_2 = (x_2,y_2)$, $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $\tilde{\lambda} = 1 - \lambda$. Then, if $x_1 \neq x_2$

\begin{equation}
g(\lambda z_1 +\tilde{\lambda}z_2)> \lambda g(z_1) +\tilde{\lambda}g(z_2)
\end{equation}

With this fact, how I can shwo that $f$ is strictly concave?

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^\alpha$ and $-y$ are concave, then so is $x^\alpha-y$.
Since concavity implies log-concavity, $f(x,y)$ is concave.

I think the same should follow from strict concavity. The sum of a strictly concave function and a concave function is strictly concave.